# Keeping the margin of the element

Tags: css

I have a element with position of

```
margin-left:241.5px
```

for the screen size 1440px = that is about 16.8%.

However , for screen size of 1920 it should be 473px.

I am trying to figure out what i can do  to dynamicly make it happen so i wont have to adjust it for every screen size.

I tried using margin-left with % but it did not work, same with EM.

Is there a way how to dynamicly make this positioning?

Its hard to stimulate demo but i tried

```
<div class="about"> 
    <p>01</p>


</div>
html,*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
html{
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.about{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(http://66.media.tumblr.com/4bb5538edf278f7e83d8275e60550433/tumblr_msefuouXB81s9yt1no1_500.png) no-repeat;
        background-size: 1158.6px 163px;
        background-position: top 172px left 149px;
        position: absolute;
}
.about p{
    margin-top: 78.3px;
        margin-left: 16.8%;
        font-size: 22px;
        position: absolute;
        color: #CECED2
}
.about h6{
    margin-top: 101.3px;
        margin-left: 241.5px;
        font-size: 22px;
        position: absolute;
        color: #151416;
}
```

Comment: You can use media query instead. Of course you will have to write for different screen sizes. but you can manage it using media query.

Comment: i wouldl like to try it if possible without media queries. It would requre media queriy for every small screen size.

Comment: Please share the demo so we can check is it possible with or without media query. Thank you

Comment: @Leothelion tried to add example , its hard to make it exact tho , will try to make better when  will have more time

Comment: May I ask in relation to what does the margin not work? ... Since it work in relation to the browsers viewport (the viewport is set to 100%) I guess you mean something else, like the image maybe? .. and if so, should the image resize and always fit viewport or should the viewport have a min-width?

Comment: Also, adding 2 images, showing the 1440 and 1920 layouts would also help understanding what you look for, and by saying at 1920 the margin should be 473, does that mean it also increases progressively, in addition to the percentage increase (since 16.8% of 1920 is 322.56)?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Not seeing your markup/CSS makes it more difficult to detect any flaws, and as percent works (seen below) there is likely something that interfere with yours, if you don't get your expected result.</strike>

As percent works (seen below) there is likely something else you expect that margin to relate to, like the background image maybe. Update your question and I will be able to address, and add, that to my answer.

*The left margin in below sample is 120px in the first and 60px in the second, showing the 20% value does work.*

```css
.parent {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: #ccc;
}
.parent + .parent {
  width: 300px;
}
.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 20%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without Script,You can only use @media screen in css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
   #your-tag{margin-left:473px}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1440px) {
   #your-tag{margin-left:241.5px}
}
```

Comment: Without a `min-width` the second media query will override the first.

Comment: I just want an example,You can use min-width and max-width together

Comment: @AkbarTaghipour Switching their order and it will work as expected (did it for you)

Answer (score 0):

Your Only other option is using css variables in conjunction with media queries

- Benefits of this approach is that you do not need to write css for each class just for the variables used inside it like critical variables and use that variable once inside the classes

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 120px) {
  :root {
    --main-margin-one: 48px;
    --main-margin-two: 58px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) and (min-width: 480px) {
  :root {
    --main-margin-one: 72px;
    --main-margin-two: 82px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 920px) and (min-width: 721px) {
  :root {
   --main-margin-one: 92px;
   --main-margin-two: 102px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1441px)and (min-width: 920px) {
  :root {
    --main-margin-one: 241.5px;
   --main-margin-two: 251.5px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1921px)and (min-width: 1441px) {
  :root {
   --main-margin-one: 440px;
   --main-margin-two: 450px;
  }
}
.className1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  margin-left: var(--main-margin-one);
}
 
.className2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  margin-left: var(--main-margin-two);
}
```

```html
<div class="className1"></div>
<div class="className2"></div>
```

[Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/#search=CSS%20Variables)

Comment: Note that CSS variables are poorly supported [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) and their MS Edge status is "under consideration".

Comment: @AndyG yes their support is very bad but since he is asking for a solution with least effort so I presented it other option would be to use calc function to generate dynamic width

Comment: I think the poor support should be mentioned in the answer. Percentages should work though, as @LGSon shows. Maybe it is the background size and position that makes the OP think the margin isn't working.

Comment: @AndyG I noticed LGS answer but it would work only immediate successor element right ?.That is the reason why I set out to find out a alternative

Comment: No, not necessarily, it depends on both markup structure, the absolute positioning and to which parent it targets and which unit type is used (i.e. vw refers to the viewport no matter markup).

Comment: Percentage width is "calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block". The about box and body (and html) all have width of 100%, without margins or padding, so the percentage will be a percentage of, effectively, the viewport width (unless there is another container element that we aren't aware of).

Comment: You shouldn't emphasize normal text like that, so I rolled it back

Comment: @AndyG the width of margin in both grid sizes were of not same percentage and I know what you told me

Comment: In question OP says for grid size he wants so and so width which is different not 16.8% of given grid sizes .That is the reason why I went for this approach as I thought it is not symmetric the margin for different grid sizes

Comment: I interpret the question to mean that the OP just wants the percentage to work, although his calculations are wrong as 16.8% of 1920 is 322.56. But maybe you are right and I've just misread it and a width of 473 is his goal. In which case, he will have to adjust it manually for different screen sizes. This "I tried using margin-left with % but it did not work" encourages my interpretation.